# While, i try to push my project to git lap

Tags: git, push

while i push my project to git lab
the first to commands are success .

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit",
```

then in the third command

```
git push -u origin main
```

getting an error like this,

```
git push -u origin main     
>>
>>
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

how can i fix this

Comment: "commit" only works locally. A "push" then should push this commit to a remote server, usually called "origin". Apparently you have not set up that remote server correctly

Comment: As you mention "the first two commands": What did you do before them? Only `git init ...`? Or `git clone ...`? Just because you can commit locally does not mean that the local repository has an idea what you mean by "origin", and you'd have to have connected to the remote repository before that

Comment: Run `git remote -v`  and see what it outputs - most probably it will be empty, as you did not add any remote repo to push to.

Comment: I'am just enter to the git so,i have lost mistake and errors,l try to figure out, thanks you for all try to help

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is the link to a remote project where to `push`.

For example:

You start from a remote project called `my-project` and `clone` it to a local folder:

```
git clone SSH_or_HTPPS_code_of_my_project

[modify something]

cd my-project

git add .

git commit -m 'first commit'

git push
```

Or you start from a local repository `my_repo`

```
cd my_repo

git init

git remote add origin SSH_or_HTPPS_code_of_my_project

[modify something]

git pull origin master # if you have files in the remote project

[modify something]

git add .
    
git commit -m 'first commit'

git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: Usual convention is to call remote repo `origin` :)

Comment: Right, updated!

Comment: @karthikakrishnankutty, you can mark as accepted if it answered your question, or let me know if it can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the process you are doing, but just to make sure - What is the output when running `git remote -v` ?

did you clone a repository or init one ? if you init a local repository, you should link it to a remote, `git remote add origin <git-repo-url>`